# Have phone rotation be camera rotation in Unity for Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

How would one go about using the gyroscope, or whatever AR-magic or related tech Android provides, to have the phone rotation become the in-3D-scene-camera rotation? Basically, I have a scene in Unity/ C#, and when it runs on Android I want to have the user be able to view the scene as if the phone was the in-world camera, a bit like in VR. So if one rotates the phone leftways, for instance, one sees what is to the left in the 3d scene, as if one was standing inside it. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html

Comment: Thank you for the link!